# Firebase Storage in Web Application: storage.useEmulator is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

In my local web application development environment the web application is accessing the Firestore emulator correctly, but not the Storage emulator. Instead it accesses the production storage.

I load the module from `http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.3.0/firebase-storage.js`

I have tried this from https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#web-v8:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
storage.useEmulator("localhost", 9199);
```

But the useEmulator function does not exist. How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `storage.useEmulator` was introduced in a later version of firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your connection before opening it?

```
var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
   authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
   databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
   storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-url>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And, I don't have direct xperience about it, but have you tried this way?

```
firebase.storage.useEmulator('localhost', xxxx)
```

And beware this could be a work in progress stuff: try this cmd:

```
firebase --open-sesame storageemulator
```